# Segmentation fault in C code function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
struct Node {
    char gender;
    int turns_in_bathroom;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Queue {
    struct Node *front, *back;
};

int QueueDeleteNext(Queue *myQueue, char value) {
Node *current_node, *previous_node;
previous_node = NULL;
int found = 0;
for (current_node = myQueue->front; current_node != NULL;
     previous_node = current_node, current_node = current_node->next) {
    if (current_node->gender == value) {
        if (previous_node == NULL) {
            myQueue->front = myQueue->back = NULL;
        }
        else {
            previous_node->next = current_node->next;
            if(previous_node->next == NULL){
                myQueue->back = previous_node;
            }
        }
        free(current_node);
        found = 1;
    }
}
return found;
}
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault on the line

```
if (current_node->gender == value) {
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why. What's going on here?
Not to mention the code will run all the way through despite the fault error in my debugger. There are some bugs that I think may be related to this, though, and I want to make sure I've got all my bases covered.

Comment: What is `Queue`?

Comment: Queue is a queue I implemented to help with the function. It's basically
   struct Node {
    char gender;
    int turns_in_bathroom;
    struct Node *next;
};

//Queue structure as a collection of Nodes
struct Queue {
    struct Node *front, *back;
};

Can't put code in the comments. I'll add it to the original post

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't stop after deleting a node. When you delete a node, you `free` it, but continue using `current_node`, which then points to an illegal memory location.

Comment: You don't show how you allocate these nodes, if at all, so the question can't really be answered.

Comment: So a simple return statement should fix the segmentation error?

Comment: 'current_node = current_node->next'.....'current_node->gender'

Comment: Please show how you call the `QueueDeleteNext` method.

Comment: When it fails, what does your debugger tell you about the value of 'current_node'?

Comment: A return statement instead of `found = 1` will avoid that `current_node` is deleted and dereferenced after that, but it will only delete the first node. If that is what you want, try it.

Comment: A return statement seemed to solve the problem, thanks

Comment: Good you solved the problem, but your code has other issues. For example, `(previous_node == NULL)` tests whether the current node is the first node in the queue. Deleting the first node does not mean that the whole queue should be deleted. That should only happen if the node to delete is the _only_ node. You also don't update the back node when the last node is deleted. Remember that after calking yourfunction, the queue must be in a sane state: Either both front and back are null or they are valid nodes and the actual front and back of the queue.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are too many problems with this code to make a single authoritative answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the problem has been solved, but there are still problems with the code:

- The condition `(previous_node == NULL)` tests whether the current node is the queue's head. In that case, the head must be dajusted instead ofthe previous node's `next`, but the code emties the whole queue without properly deleting possible trailing enodes.
- When the last node in the queue is deleted, the queue's back should be updated, so that subsequent pushes can append to the end.

Finally, it looks a bit as if the intention of the OP was to delete all nodes with the corresponding value, because the execution didn't stop after the first deletion. So let's do that and return the number of deleted nodes:

```
int QueueDeleteNext(struct Queue *q, char value)
{
    struct Node *prev = NULL;
    struct Node *curr = q->front;
    int count = 0;

    while (curr) {
        if (curr->gender == value) {
            struct Node *nn = curr;

            if (prev == NULL) {
                q->front = curr->next;
            } else {
                prev->next = curr->next;
            }

            if (curr == q->back) q->back = prev;

            curr = curr->next;

            free(nn);
            count++;
        } else {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

The main loop is now a `while` loop that treats deleting and skipping a node differently. In bothcases, the next node is `curr->next`, but when a node is deleted, the `prev`node stays the same! This code also preserves the back of the queue.

Another way to implement this is to use a pointer to node pointer instead to a `prev` pointer. This eliminates the need to distinguish between the head and other nodes. `nd` is the address of the queue's head at first and the address of the previous node's ´next`field after that. The code updates the pointer that points to the current node via`nd`:

```
int QueueDeleteNext(struct Queue *q, char value)
{
    struct Node **nd = &q->front;
    int count = 0;

    q->back = NULL;

    while (*nd) {
        if ((*nd)->gender == value) {
            struct Node *nn = *nd;

            (*nd) = (*nd)->next;

            free(nn);
            count++;
        } else {
            q->back = *nd;
            nd = &(*nd)->next;
        }            
    }

    return count;
}
```

This code can be extended to just delete the first node or the first _n_nodes.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (current_node = myQueue->front; current_node != NULL;
 previous_node = current_node, current_node = current_node->next)
```

At the end of each iteration of your for loop, you ask for current_node to point on his next element. Yet, some lines below:

```
free(current_node);
```

You free this node. So it is pointing on nothing allocated anymore, leading to the segmentation fault you are getting later. Just exit the function as soon as you find the element you want to delete:

```
int QueueDeleteNext(Queue *myQueue, char value) {
Node *current_node, *previous_node;
previous_node = NULL;
for (current_node = myQueue->front; current_node != NULL;
     previous_node = current_node, current_node = current_node->next) {
    if (current_node->gender == value) {
        if (previous_node == NULL) {
            myQueue->front = myQueue->back = NULL;
        }
        else {
            previous_node->next = current_node->next;
            if(previous_node->next == NULL){
                myQueue->back = previous_node;
            }
        }
        free(current_node);
        return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding a return statement after found = 1; stopped the debugger from throwing the error.